# Which are the cheapest train from CDG airport, Paris to Renne?

Tags: trains

I will go from Charles De Gaulle Airport to Renne by Train, in France.

Which are the cheapest train within 10-15 Euro ?

Comment: Did you try google?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Train fares vary depending on the route, demand, when you book, your eligibility for discounts, and other factors. You can use [the SNCF website](https://en.oui.sncf/en/) to look up the options for your dates and times. With a booking sufficiently far in advance, there are some TGV options for €20, but bookings with less notice or more desirable trains will cost more.

The bus might be cheaper as well. There are bus fares listed on the SNCF website too (just switch the tab from train to bus), but you can also [search on Rome2Rio](https://www.rome2rio.com/map/Paris-CDG-Airport-CDG/Rennes), which will show you FlixBus buses too.

Comment: The OUIBUS  starts from Paris centre-Bercy- Seine   for Renne.  My question is how far  is the distance from Paris centre-Bercy- Seine to  CDG airport ?

Comment: @M.A.SARKAR Around 30km. Bercy is in the center of Paris, while the airport is very much not. You can get there by train from the airport, but you can also just book an Ouibus ticket from the airport to Rennes. They'll have one bus take you from the airport to the bus terminal in Paris, and another bus take you from Paris to Rennes. When you search for buses on the SNCF website, look for the ones leaving from CDG.

Comment: Yes I am searching but not gettimg from airport to renne.  Do I need to book advance for the renne bus from airport ?

Comment: @M.A.SARKAR No. Just go to [the SNCF site](https://en.oui.sncf/en/), choose bus, put in CDG under From (it will say "Paris Roissy Charles de Gaulle Airport") and Rennes under To. When you get the results, you want the departures from CDG, not the ones that say Orly (a different airport) or anything else that it puts up there. Of course, if you aren't booking in advance, it will generally cost more, but every trip has a different price.

Comment: I need t go 'Universite De Renne 1  from CDG airport.  So at which stoppage I should stop by Bus from CDG airport ?  It is showing Renne (Brittany) online. Is it near to Renne universite 1 ?  There are other stopage like Rennes-le-Chateu,  Rennes-en-Greneulles, Rennes-les-Bains, Rennes-sur-Loue. Which one is neaer to University De Renne 1 ?

Comment: I've never been to Rennes, so I'd just be using Google Maps the same as you. I can tell you that some of the places you've listed are hundreds of kilometers in the wrong direction, so you don't want to go to Rennes-sur-Loue for sure. The main Rennes train station is [about 1.5 km from the university](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Gare+Rennes,+Place+de+la+Gare,+Rennes,+France/University+of+Rennes+1,+Rue+du+Thabor,+35000+Rennes,+France/), with a bus and metro available to reduce that distance.

Comment: And if [the website is accurate](https://www.ouibus.com/destinations/rennes#arrets), the train station is the only Ouibus stop in Rennes.

Comment: Sorry for quoting all station but the bus says it has stopage at Renne. Thanks

Comment: M.A. SARKAR, Renne**s** has an 's' at the end.